# Python Game Programming

Tags: python, opengl

Where can i find a decent resource to learn game programming in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html). It's also a framework designed specifically for creating games in Python.

[Invent Your Own Computer Games with Python](http://inventwithpython.com/) is a great online book on the subject.

Comment: i have that book. i was looking to further my skills. moving away from the shell/prompt.

Comment: @iKlsR then you should start reading the documentation for PyGame and Python, that way you can become a Python game-dev pro. What do you mean by moving away from the shell?

Comment: the default >> print('crap') and the command prompt, i want to start  creating gui with graphics.

Comment: @iKlsR how far did you make it in the book? I know there are sections about graphics, but they're towards the end. You have to learn the basics of Python before you can get there.

Comment: i finished it. yes there are some really good examples in there but im thirsty for more. :)

Comment: @iKlsR there are some great tutorials and examples on the PyGame site.

Comment: i was more interested in working without a library but i guess its a good place to start. thanks for all your help. :)

Comment: @iklsR if you want to work w/o a library, Python's not the place to go. I'd recommend C++, then (or XNA, if you're on Windows and would like to try your hand at C#)

Comment: i prefer c++, but again, its not the language, im fairly verse with the console applications, i just want to start creating applications with a gui with controls.

Comment: @iKlsR not games? Then you should use Tkinter, it comes with Python and it's very simple

Answer (score 1):

- The pygame wiki has a page with tutorials:
  http://www.pygame.org/wiki/tutorials

I've made a game after sorta paging through tutorials and docs, though obviously pygame is only one (though a pretty popular) game library for python

- This book is very highly rated (though I've not read it myself, others have pointed me there):
  [http://www.amazon.com/Game-Programming-Python-Development/dp/1584502584](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584502584)
- Finally, simply googling "python game framework" gets you pretty far, and lets you evaluate your options. Pygame is a great starting point, as a very generalist approach which handles input,drawing, and sound all in one library, but many frameworks exist for more specific tasks as well.